# Adding a button to the end of the grouped gridview

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am looking into adding a button to the "end" of the grid view.

The idea is that I have a grouped view showing groups and items with in these groups. I only show some of the items within the group and wants to show a "load more" button at the end of the items shown.

[image]

I have tried all kinds of things in the standard grouped items page with no luck.

Any good ideas?

Thanks in advance

Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to follow the approach used by most existing apps: Allow the user to click on the header to display all the items.

You can also add the "Load More" button as if it was a normal grid item. Then, style it differently using a different template and ItemTemplateSelector.

Finally, the most complex (and flexible) solution would be to put the "Load More" button above the GridView, and manually sync its location when the GridView is scrolled...